# Can't see/load a .obj file with Qt3D, written in cpp

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qt3d

I'm having a lot of issues to have a simple working app that load a light mesh in Qt3D, nothing shows up on screen.

Here's some code I put together to have a have striped down to show.

You'll notice that it's a shorter version of [this Qt example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html)

- You won't see it in this example but in my actual project I already
  tried loading it with

  - qrc and
  - localfile `QUrl`
- `Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh` work without an issue.
- I tried to watch the loading status of the mesh, on my actual project it does go from `None` though `Loading` to `Loaded`
- Also, I have no trouble loading the file `su.obj` using a Qt QML example, so it's
  not the file that is corrupted. The file being a simple Suzanne from Blender, exported.
- I used Qt5 and 6.
- Finally, I know the question has been asked a few times, but nothing helped.

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCameraLens>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DCore/QAspectEngine>

#include <Qt3DInput/QInputAspect>

#include <Qt3DRender/QRenderAspect>
#include <Qt3DRender/QGeometryRenderer>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QForwardRenderer>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QSphereMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QTorusMesh>

#include <QMesh>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

#include "orbittransformcontroller.h"
#include "qorbitcameracontroller.h"
#include "qt3dwindow.h"
#include <qdebug.h>

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene()
{
    // Root entity
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    // Material
    Qt3DRender::QMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(rootEntity);

    // Sphere
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *sphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    auto *sphereMesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh();
    sphereMesh->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("su.obj"));

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    OrbitTransformController *controller = new OrbitTransformController(sphereTransform);
    controller->setTarget(sphereTransform);
    controller->setRadius(20.0f);

    QPropertyAnimation *sphereRotateTransformAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(sphereTransform);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setTargetObject(controller);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setPropertyName("angle");
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setStartValue(QVariant::fromValue(0));
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setEndValue(QVariant::fromValue(360));
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setDuration(10000);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setLoopCount(-1);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->start();

    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMesh);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereTransform);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(material);

    return rootEntity;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *scene = createScene();

    // Camera
    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // For camera controls
    Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(scene);
    camController->setLinearSpeed( 50.0f );
    camController->setLookSpeed( 180.0f );
    camController->setCamera(camera);

    view.setRootEntity(scene);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: change `su.obj` to `/fullpath/of/su.obj`

Comment: It actually works !
I'll try to make it work with qrc or relative (I obviously can't let it as a absolute path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @eyllanesc and qDebug, I found how to write it in three ways:

- ```
  const QUrl url = QUrl( "qrc:/path/copied/from/qtcreator/su.obj");
  ```
- ```
   const QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile( "C:/path/to/folder/su.obj");
  ```
- ```
   const QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile( "su.obj");
  ```

  - ```
     qDebug() << QDir::currentPath(); // I used this to make sure I was at the right place
    ```

and

```
sphereMesh->setSource(url);
```